# How to remove white space around bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I am trying to make a bar chart in python using matplotlib. 
Here is my code

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6.5, 3), dpi=300) 
plt.bar(y_pos, X, align='center', color='red', ecolor='black')
plt.bar(y_pos, X, align='center', color='green', ecolor='black')
plt.bar(y_pos, X, align='center', color='blue', ecolor='black')
plt.bar(y_pos, X, align='center', color='orange', ecolor='black')

plt.ylabel("Rate", size=8)
plt.xlabel("Label", size=8)
plt.xticks(np.arange(1,57,1))
plt.ylim([50,100])
plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=4)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=6)
plt.show()
```

But problem is the unwanted space around the bars. How can I remove this white space?
  [image]

Comment: `plt.margins(0)`?

Comment: It works, Thanks. @DavidG

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`tight_layout()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.tight_layout) before displaying the figure.

Comment: tight_layout() doesn't remove white space. plt.margins(0) woked

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the follow-up